# UML class diagrams - how do I draw a class diagram that shows a self-reference?

Tags: interfaces, uml, class, dependencies, class-diagram

So I have the following case. I have an interface `A` and an implementation `AImpl`. Now I have another implementation of `A`, called `A2Impl`, which references any instance of `A` besides implementing `A` already.

So I have now drawn the following UML class diagram:

[image]

Would this be correct? How do i draws this correctly?

Comment: Which UML notation are you implementing? Implement, extends and composition are drawn with different line styles and arrows.

Comment: i am using whatever is on the english wikipedia article for class diagrams

Comment: Well, the answer to the question is *yes* you can draw such a relationship between A, AImpl and A2Impl but for the sake of the "readability" do use the proper [notation](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_clases) to represent the different kinds of associations.

Comment: So, I took a look at this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

Comment: Check the first image in "Relationships".

Comment: Look at any two language versions of the same wikipedia article, there'll be differences. I have a book too ... also different. I tried looking at the spec and that stuff is way too weirdly strucutred. Isn't there like an official easy to understand go-to-ressource?

Comment: "Is this right?" is quite hard to answer because it's very open-ended. Could you explain why you think it's wrong, so that answers can address the core of the issue rather than try to fill in the blanks with assumptions that may not matter to your particular use case?

Comment: Your diagram is a correct UML diagram, except that the dotted lines should be dashed lines.

Comment: @Flater Well, I have never seen something like this before, so I wasn't sure whether it is how you'd do it. Who knows, maybe it is discouraged to have multiple types of relation between two classes. Anyway, the answer that www.admiraalit.nl has given me seems quite satisfactory.

Comment: @Marcel: Just to clarify (happy you alredy got an answer): the given answer suggests that your question was more about the format of the UML than the data structure it's representing. The way I read your question, it seemed to ask about the structure itself. That distinction is important since it leads to a very different answer.

Comment: @Flater So you are saying that I could improve the structure? When you say structure, do you mean the layout (visual structure) or the logical structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, but not optimal.

The dependency just says 'A2Impl' cannot do without 'A', but that is obvious, since A2Impl implements A. In fact, the 'implements' relationship implies the dependency.

If A2Impl has a permanent reference to another instance of A, it would be better to replace the dependency by an association (an arrow with a solid line instead of a dashed line). You may wish to add multiplicities to the association (not mandatory). In the figure below, I have specified multiplicity "1" to indicate that every instance of A2Impl always refers to exactly one instance of A.

[image: cd]

If you think an association is not appropriate, you could also assign a stereotype to the dependency, to indicate the type of dependency, e.g. «call».